# What happens if you uncheck iCloud for photos?

Tags: mac, icloud, photos.app

I accidentally unchecked iCloud for photos on my Mac and quickly turned it on again. Does anything happen when you do that? I think I have read that if you turn off iCloud, your photos will get deleted within 30 days. Could this happen even though I only unchecked iCloud for a short while?
I have attached a picture of the place I unchecked iCloud for photos (even though it is turned on it this picture). It is marked by a read circle. The text above the box says: "Apps using iCloud".

Thanks in advance:-) [image]

Comment: Turning off iCloud may delete the photos from your device depending on your setting, but will not delete it from your iCloud. Read [What Hap­pens When You Dis­able and Delete Pho­tos from iCloud](https://www.guidingtech.com/what-happens-disable-delete-photos-icloud/) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using iCloud photos somewhere else all turning it off does is stops them from updating on your mac. Your photos won't get deleted immediately from iCloud if you turn it off and you only have it turned on o your mac, and they will stay on your mac.

Comment: Thanks. When you say that the photos won't get deleted immediately, does that mean it will happen eventually? Now that I have turned on iCloud again, will it start updating again?

Comment: @Katrine If you only have iCloud on your mac and you turn it off it'll be 30 before they delete from iCloud. Now that you have it back on it'll start updating again.